# My weapon only works on NPC's and not players

Tags: lua, roblox

So basically I made a weapon it flings people after you hit them but it only works on NPC's and not players. Could someone explain to me why this is?

```
local power = 5

local function fling(character)
    local humanoid = character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")
    local rootpart
    if humanoid then
        humanoid:ChangeState(11)
        rootpart = humanoid.RootPart
    end
    if not rootpart then
        rootpart = character.AssemblyRootPart
    end
    if rootpart then
        rootpart.Velocity = Vector3.new(math.random(-100, 100), math.random(50, 100), math.random(-100, 100)) * 10
    end
end

local tool = script.Parent
local handle = tool:WaitForChild("Handle")
local slash = script:WaitForChild("Slash")
local debounce = false
local idle = false
local PlayersHit = {}
local playerService = game:GetService("Players")
local plr = playerService:GetPlayerFromCharacter(tool.Parent)

local Datastore2 = require(game.ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("Modules").Datastore2)

local defaulthits = 0

local hitds = Datastore2("hits",plr)

tool.Activated:Connect(function()
    if idle == false and debounce == false then 
        debounce = true
        
        local humanoid = tool.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
        local animtrack = humanoid:LoadAnimation(slash)
            
        animtrack:Play()
        wait(1)
        debounce = false
        idle = false
    end
end)

handle.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") and hit.Parent ~= tool.Parent then
        if debounce == true and PlayersHit[hit.Parent] == nil then
            
            fling(hit.Parent)

            hitds:Increment(1, defaulthits)
            debounce = false
            script.Parent.Handle.hit:Play()
        end
    end
end)
```

This is my current code. I do not know what to do I'm pretty sure its something to do with the fling script.

Answer (score 0):

I found out how instead of humanoid:changestate(11) i used humanoid.PlatformStand = true